# Show numeric keyboard using <input> on iPad with iOS 16.2

Tags: html, ios, ipad

I cannot get my iPad on iOS 16.2 to show a numeric keyboard.

What I've tried:

```
inputmode="numeric"
```

```
inputmode="decimal"
```

```
pattern="[0-9]+"
```

```
type="number"
```

Nothing seems to work.

On iPhone though it seems to work fine.

iPhone:

[image]

iPad:

[image]

Comment: There is no number pad on an iPad. Even in a native iOS app on an iPad, there is no built-in number pad. The keyboard showing numbers and symbols (as shown in your question) is the closest you can get.